# Linha com valor NULL é desconsiderada pela função SUM?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, ansi

Participei do concurso do IFNMG, prova elaborada pela Fundação CEFET. 
Resolvi a questão a seguir e marquei a letra C, mas o gabarito diz que o correto é a letra A.

**Questão 31**
Considere que a tabela NotaFiscalItem está armazenada em um
sistema gerenciador de banco de dados (SGBD) relacional, contendo os seguintes dados.
**Tabela: NotaFiscalItem**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida, observe o comando SQL apresentado a seguir.
**Figura: Comando SQL**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado produzido pela execução do comando SQL, ao considerar os dados apresentados na tabela NotaFiscalItem, é
a) 28,00 7,00 48,00
b) 28,00 NULL NULL
c) 48,00 7,00 48,00
d) 48,00 0,00 55,00
e) NULL NULL NULL

A instrução "sum(qtd_item*vlr_unitario - vlr_desconto)" não soma a primeira linha por conta do "null" na coluna "vlr_desconto"? Mas isso não depende do SGBD que se está utilizando?

Comment: Poderia transcrever o enunciado da questão na sua pergunta? Deixá-la como imagem prejudica sua publicação, pois muitos usuários não conseguem visualizar as imagens e o sistema de busca não indexa seu conteúdo.

Comment: Ok, o que estiver em texto vou deixar em texto, mas a tabela e a instrução é figura. Obrigado

Comment: Sim, o `NULL` invalida o resto do cálculo. `(2*10 - NULL)` vai sempre retornar `NULL`. Para que fosse a opção A teria que ter dessa forma (existem outras): `sum(qtd_item*vlr_unitario - ISNULL(vlr_desconto, 0)`.

Comment: @JoãoMartins na verdade no MySQL não funciona dessa forma...

Comment: @Sorack como sabia que era MySQL e não SQL Server?

Comment: Não foi especificado o SGBD e é justamente neste ponto que acho que a questão é pode ser anulada.

Comment: @JoãoMartins não sei qual o SGBD, dei só um exemplo mesmo... na real acho que a questão trata do padrão ANSI

Comment: @Sorack Sim, mas mesmo assim teria que ter especificado no enunciado que se trata do padrão ANSI e não de um SGBD específico, já que dependendo do SGBD o comportamento pode ser diferente.

Comment: @DenisCaixeta entendi. E mesmo assim fica parecendo que é uma pegadinha já que tem comportamentos diferentes mesmo

Comment: Os bancos relacionais possuem comportamentos diferentes com relação a essa questão do nulo. O Firebird retornaria null em todos os três cálculos, já o mysql ignoraria os nulos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na [documentação de funções agrupadas do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

> ... group functions ignore NULL values.

OU em tradução livre:

> ... funções agrupadas ignoram valores NULOS.

No `SQL Server` o `NULL` de colunas agrupadas invalida a expressão, então para responder com precisão essa questão seria necessário saber qual o `SGBD` utilizado, porém segundo [esta página](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sql-in-a/9780596155322/ch04s02.html) (a qual não posso atestar com 100% de certeza a veracidade), no padrão `ANSI` todas as funções agregadas, exceto `COUNT` vão ignorar os valores `NULL` ao computar seus resultados.

---

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE NotaFiscalItem(
  nro_nota_fiscal int,
  nro_item smallint,
  qtd_item smallint,
  vlr_unitario numeric(7, 2),
  vlr_desconto numeric(7, 2)
);

INSERT INTO NotaFiscalItem VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 10.00, NULL),
(1, 2, 2, 7.50, 2.00),
(1, 3, 1, 20.00, 5.00);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT SUM(qtd_item * vlr_unitario - vlr_desconto),
       SUM(vlr_desconto),
       SUM(qtd_item * vlr_unitario) - SUM(vlr_desconto)
  FROM NotaFiscalItem;
```

**Resultado:**

```
| SUM(qtd_item * vlr_unitario - vlr_desconto) | SUM(vlr_desconto) | SUM(qtd_item * vlr_unitario) - SUM(vlr_desconto) |
| ------------------------------------------- | ----------------- | ------------------------------------------------ |
| 28                                          | 7                 | 48                                               |
```

Você pode verificar a execução no [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nimXuoBMRc5H7rQzavkVzq/0).

Comment: Então a questão deve ser anulada, pois deveria ter especificado o SGBD? Vou entrar com recurso.

Comment: @DenisCaixeta coloquei uma informação extra. No padrão `ANSI`, aparentemente, o `NULL`é apenas ignorado

Answer (score 4):

Para criar o banco de dados:

```
CREATE TABLE NotaFiscalItem (
  nro_nota_fiscal integer,
  nro_item smallint,
  qtd_item smallint,
  vlr_unitario numeric(7, 2),
  vlr_desconto numeric(7, 2)
);

INSERT INTO NotaFiscalItem (nro_nota_fiscal, nro_item, qtd_item, vlr_unitario, vlr_desconto) VALUES (1, 1, 2, 10, NULL);
INSERT INTO NotaFiscalItem (nro_nota_fiscal, nro_item, qtd_item, vlr_unitario, vlr_desconto) VALUES (1, 2, 2, 7.50, 2.00);
INSERT INTO NotaFiscalItem (nro_nota_fiscal, nro_item, qtd_item, vlr_unitario, vlr_desconto) VALUES (1, 3, 1, 20.00, 5.00);
```

Transcrevendo o SELECT:

```
Select sum(qtd_item*vlr_unitario - vlr_desconto),
       sum(vlr_desconto),
       sum(qtd_item*vlr_unitario) - sum(vlr_desconto)
  from NotaFiscalItem
```

Ao executar isso (no MySQL 5.6), veio essa resposta:

```
28    7    48
```

Comment: :P pela imagem tem um cara de ser o postgres. No [soen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12730751/1342547) e no [dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/25435/30082) existem perguntas sobre o tema também. Só é complicado inferir se é sobre o banco de dados ou sobre o padrão ANSI.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar `COALESCE`

ex:

```
SELECT coalesce(sum(qtd_item*vlr_unitario - vlr_desconto),0) from NotaFiscalItem
```